# what is mean by this "$books = $this->model->getBookList();" $this with two -> -> means

Tags: php

i am reading MVC.
i found this  "$books = $this->model->getBookList();" $this with two -> -> means
what is mean by this

Comment: Where two `->->`? I see only one

Comment: in php the "->" is how you access the property/method of an object

Comment: For reference, you probably should look into the basics of object oriented programming

Answer (score 3):

It means `$this` is an object, you access the object's `$model` property using `$this->model`. And `$model` is also an object, and you access that object's `getBookList` function using `$this->model->getBookList();`.

A sample might look something like this:

```
class Model
{
    public function getBookList()
    {
        // return book list
    }
}

class A
{
    private $model;

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // $this means "this instance of class A"
        // $this->model means "this instance of class A's $model property
        $this->model = new Model();

        // this will call the getBookList function of class Model:
        echo $this->model->getBookList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`->` in PHP allows you to access a property or method of an object.

When you call `$this->model`, you get the `model` property of the object instance in `$this`.  In PHP, you can then keep going to call the  `->getBookList()` on that object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could say from your question, this means you are getting a list from the method getBookList in a subclass model of the current working class (this).